# Event raise-handling in Java

Tags: java, events

How to raise custom events and handle in Java. Some links will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You should try to elaborate a little bit on what you're after. What kind of events? There are no intrinsic events in Java, perhaps exceptions is what you're after?

Comment: Like this
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csevents01.aspx

Comment: Yes, Roe. I am aware that the link points to a c# article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following linked helped me to understand.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-03/01-qa-0315-happyevent.html

Comment: Hey you can accept your own answer if it is more appropriate than any other answer

Answer (score 15):

There are no first-class events in Java. All event handling is done using interfaces and listener pattern. For example:

```
// Roughly analogous to .NET EventArgs
class ClickEvent extends  java.util.EventObject {
  public ClickEvent(Object source) {
    super(source);
  }
}

// Roughly analogous to .NET delegate
interface ClickListener extends  java.util.EventListener {
  void clicked(ClickEvent e);
} 

class Button {
  // Two methods and field roughly analogous to .NET event with explicit add and remove accessors
  // Listener list is typically reused between several events
  
  private EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();

  void addClickListener(ClickListener l) {
    clickListenerList.add(ClickListener.class, l)
  }

  void removeClickListener(ClickListener l) {
    clickListenerList.remove(ClickListener.class, l)
  }

  // Roughly analogous to .net OnEvent protected virtual method pattern -
  // call this method to raise the event
  protected void fireClicked(ClickEvent e) {
    ClickListener[] ls = listenerList.getListeners(ClickEvent.class);
    for (ClickListener l : ls) {
      l.clicked(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Client code typically uses anonymous inner classes to register handlers:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
  public void clicked(ClickEvent e) {
    // handle event
  }
});
```

Comment: I take it EventListenerList is just an ArrayList typed to your listener class?

Comment: Nope, found you have a `getListeners` method - where does this class come from?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html

Comment: Thanks @Pavel for the link.  Everyone else: Questions/Answers are much more clear with "imports" statements (and no "*" imports).

Comment: Hm.. I find it very curious that EventListener is in "java.util" (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html) but EventListenerList is in "swing.event" : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html     Makes me skeptical to "trust' it.  :0

Answer (score 6):

Java lacks intrinsic event handling, but there are libraries to help you accomplish this. Check out javaEventing, http://code.google.com/p/javaeventing/ 
It works much as in C# where you first define your events, and then register event listeners. You trigger events using EventManager.triggerEvent(..someEvent). It allows you to provide custom conditions and payloads with your events as well.

bob

Answer (score 3):

Java hasn't built-in support for delegates and events like C#. You would need to implement the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or [Publish/Subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a .net type delegate event, I propose this templated solution. 
It's advantage is that no hard casts are required, and a listener could implement several "events" as long as they are using different event classes.

```
import java.util.EventListener;
import java.util.EventObject;
// replaces the .net delegate

public interface GenericEventListener<EventArgsType extends EventObject>
    extends EventListener {
    public void eventFired(EventArgsType e);
}

//------------------------------------------------

import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.Vector;
// replaces the .net Event keyword

public class GenericEventSource<EventArgsType extends EventObject> {
    private Vector<GenericEventListener<EventArgsType>> listenerList =
        new Vector<GenericEventListener<EventArgsType>>();

    //TODO handle multi-threading lock issues
    public void addListener(GenericEventListener<EventArgsType> listener) {
        listenerList.add(listener);
    }

    //TODO handle multi-threading lock issues
    public void raise(EventArgsType e) {
        for (GenericEventListener<EventArgsType> listener : listenerList) {
            listener.eventFired(e);
        }
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------

// like a .net class extending EventArgs
public class MyCustomEventArgs extends EventObject {
    private int arg;
    public MyCustomEventArgs(Object source, int arg) {
        super(source);
        this.arg = arg;
    }
    public int getArg() {
        return arg;
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------

// replaces the .net event handler function. Can be put in a nested class, Java style
// Listener can handle several event types if they have different EventArg classes
public class MyCustomListener implements GenericEventListener<MyCustomEventArgs> {
    private Object source = null;
    private int arg;
    public void eventFired(MyCustomEventArgs e) {
        source = e.getSource();
        arg = e.getArg();
        // continue handling event...
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------

import GenericEventListener;
import GenericEventSource;
// this is the class that would like to throw events (e.g. MyButton)
public class MyCustomEventSource {
    // This is like declaring a .net public Event field of a specific delegate type
    GenericEventSource<MyCustomEventArgs> myEvent = new GenericEventSource<MyCustomEventArgs>();

    public GenericEventSource<MyCustomEventArgs> getEvent() {
        return myEvent;
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------

// Examples of using the event
MyCustomListener myListener1 = new MyCustomListener();
MyCustomEventSource mySource = new MyCustomEventSource();
mySource.getEvent().addListener( myListener1 );
mySource.getEvent().raise( new MyCustomEventArgs(mySource,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has no in-language support for events handling. But there's some classes that can help. You may look at `java.awt.Event` class; [`java.awt.event`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/package-summary.html) and [`java.beans`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html) packages. First package is a base for event handling in AWT and Swing GUI libraries. `java.beans` package contains supporting stuff for [Java Beans specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javabeans/docs/spec.html), including property change events and bean context events.

Generally, event handling is implemented according to Observer or Publish/Subscribe patterns (as mentioned by [kgiannakakis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24054/kgiannakakis))